# Setup of PyDev and Eclipse for Blender Add-Ons

Tags: eclipse, pydev, blender

I followed the instructions in this [ebook Programming Add-Ons for Blender 2.5](http://airplanes3d.net/pydev-000_e.xml) to setup a development environment.

Currently I try to debug an installed [add-on called Bloop](http://dm.tzi.de/bloop/) although it seems to work, eclipse still shows many error messages like:

```
class Mapping(object):

    def __init__(self, joint=None, id=None, bone=None, other=None):
        ...
        self.bone_matrix = bpy.bloop.armature.matrix_world.inverted() * self.bone.bone.matrix_local.inverted()
                               ^^^^
                               ErrorMsg: Undefined variable from import: bloop
```

The external libraries are configured as follows:

[image]

Blenders version is 2.67, the add-on was developed for 2.59. I have absolutely no experience with Python in blender.

Another type of errors is:

```
Unresolved import: MappingSet   bloop.py

from .mapping_set import MappingSet
```

Where MappingSet is in the same folder as bloop.py which tries to import.

The projects structure is as follows (I don't have a source folder since I want to edit in place)

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

A workaround to suppress at least the error messages is using #@UnresolvedImport and #@UndefinedVariable at the end of those lines.

Comment: *Blenders version is 2.67, the add-on was developed for 2.59.* This could be the problem, have you tried running it in 2.67? The API changes nearly every release.

Comment: As @iKlsR said, ensure that the add-on works and is enabled. Test in  blenders internal python console type print(bpy.bloop). I doubt it works due to the mentioned changed API. 

I would also not rely on the pydef generator as it only really works with 2.59.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I setup debug differently but still based on the lux-render tutorial.

First, create the a .py file, lets call it debug.py, which will contain a function which we will call later to setup debugging. Put this file in the same folder as the main `__init__.py` of your module. As per the lux-renderer tutorial, add the following code, updating PYDEV_SOURCE_DIR.

```
import sys

def startdebug():
    try:
        # set the PYDEV_SOURCE_DIR correctly before using the debugger
        PYDEV_SOURCE_DIR = 'C:\Program Files\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev.debug_2.5.0.2012040618\pysrc'

        # test if PYDEV_SOURCE_DIR already in sys.path, otherwise append it
        if sys.path.count(PYDEV_SOURCE_DIR) < 1:
            sys.path.append(PYDEV_SOURCE_DIR)

        # import pydevd module
        import pydevd

        # set debugging enabled
        pydevd.settrace(None, True, True, 5678, False, False)
    except:
        pass
```

When setting the PYDEV_SOURCE_DIR ensure you point it to the org.python.pydev.debug_xxxxx. There is another folder similiar to this. To ensure you have the correct folder it will contain a /pysrc folder.

Now in your main `__init__.py`, this must come before any other import statements to work correctly. Add the following directly under the bl_info section, as strangely blender parses this itself.

```
DEBUGGING = True
if(DEBUGGING):
    import debug
    debug.startdebug()
```

Having it here will avoids adding per file traces like the lux-render tutorial.

1. Add some breakpoint to the version in the add-ons folder,
2. Switch to the debug perspective,
3. Start Eclipses debug server,
4. Start blender
5. Run the script and it will hit the breakpoint.

The common problems I find people encounter:

- pointing the path to the wrong pydev debug folder, ensure that there is a /pysrc folder
- When Pydev updates, update the PYDEV_SOURCE_DIR as the debug_xxxxx will have change
- not having eclipse server running,
- setting breakpoints on a local copy of the files instead of the version in the blender add-on directory
- saving the script does not mean that blender will reload it, use imp, disable/renable the add-on or restart Blender.

There are good instructions for setting up blender and eclipse for debugging.
http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User:Z0r/PyDevAndProfiling

While this is for blenders game engine, much of it applies to regular blender. Hope this help!

**EDIT:** I deleted it because I felt that this doesn't answer your question. But here it is since you insisted.

Comment: @stacker I deleted it because I felt that this doesn't answer your question. But here it is since you insisted.